# Phalcon dispatching execute two actions instead of one

Tags: controller, router, phalcon

i will try to explain my problem.

When dispatcher call dispatch method it execute two controller actions instead of one. First it execute correct action and after this it always execute defined notFound action.
No output from notFound action is render. I found this then i put some database logging logic in my notFound action. With every request new records appear in my db table which is not expexted.

My code looks like this:

```
$d = new Dispatcher();
$d->setDI($di);
$d->setControllerName($router->getControllerName());
$d->setActionName($router->getActionName());
$d->setParams($router->getParams());

$d->dispatch();
```

Then i saw a problem here i tried to debug a lit with this code, but it goes right way, everything works fine:

```
$d = new Dispatcher();
$d->setDI($di);
$d->setControllerName("login");
$d->setActionName("index");
$d->setParams(array());

$d->dispatch();
```

So i try to do it this way, but this don't work:

```
$controller = $router->getControllerName();
$action = $router->getActionName();
$params = $router->getParams();

$d = new Dispatcher();
$d->setDI($di);
$d->setControllerName($controller);
$d->setActionName($action);
$d->setParams($params);

$d->dispatch();
```

Then i decide that router is the bad guy here and try this and expecting bad results:

```
$controller = $router->getControllerName();
$action = $router->getActionName();
$params = $router->getParams();

$d = new Dispatcher();
$d->setDI($di);
$d->setControllerName("login");
$d->setActionName("index");
$d->setParams(array());

$d->dispatch();
```

But everithing works fine. Please tell me what's going on and what am i doing wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Router got to invoke handle method. Then it will know about controller and action to prefer.
About two calls. Is there normal Application bootstrapped? Why you are choosing to make custom behavior for your app? Where exactly that behavior happens?

Comment: At first i used normal bootstrap, the one which was generated by phalcon-devtools but it did not work. so i decide to try to write my own one.

Comment: here you can find some examples and find out how does it works. hope, could be useful http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/applications.html#manual-bootstraping